# Going to vs to go to

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference

> 1. Don't you need **to go to** the bus stop?
> 2. Don't you need **going to** the bus stop?

Which of the sentences above is more informal or common to use? I think they mean the same, but the second phrase is just a shorter way to say the same thing?

Comment: You need a short action, so use "go to"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

The first choice is correct:

> Don't you need to go to the bus stop?

The idea of "must do something" using the verb "need" is expressed as "need + to + (infinitive form of verb)"

### Additional info

Also, the two choices do not mean the same thing. The second choice, actually is not used at all.

The pattern of "need + (gerund form of verb)" has a different meaning. This means to have a need for the act of something done by someone/something outside of the subject: "need healing" = "need to be healed by a healer or by some medicine".